# Compare dates in for-each in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

Sample XML:

```
    <ProductRevision id="id38" name="Item1" accessRefs="#id4" subType="ItemRev" masterRef="#id36" revision="A">
  <UserData id="id39">
    <UserValue value="2015-08-11T16:46:20" title="date_released"></UserValue>
  </UserData>  
</ProductRevision>

<ProductRevision id="id53" name="Item2" accessRefs="#id4" subType="ItemRev" masterRef="#id51" revision="A">
  <UserData id="id40">
    <UserValue value="2015-08-07T13:57:42" title="date_released"></UserValue>
  </UserData>  
</ProductRevision>

<ProductRevision id="id68" name="Item2" accessRefs="#id4" subType="ItemRev" masterRef="#id66" revision="A">
  <UserData id="id41">
    <UserValue value="2015-08-06T13:57:42" title="date_released"></UserValue>
  </UserData>  
</ProductRevision>

<Product id="id36" name="Item1" accessRefs="#id4" subType="Item" productId="1234">
  <ApplicationRef version="g7cVc2GTznicWC" application="Teamcenter" label="g7cVc2GTznicWC"></ApplicationRef>
  <AssociatedForm id="id50" role="IMAN_master_form" formRef="#id48"></AssociatedForm>
</Product>
<Product id="id51" name="Item2" accessRefs="#id4" subType="Item" productId="BXU004846">
  <ApplicationRef version="gLZVMV_wznicWC" application="Teamcenter" label="gLZVMV_wznicWC"></ApplicationRef>
  <AssociatedForm id="id65" role="IMAN_master_form" formRef="#id63"></AssociatedForm>
</Product>
<Product id="id66" name="Item3" accessRefs="#id4" subType="Item" productId="BXU004848">
  <ApplicationRef version="weVVMpxFznicWC" application="Teamcenter" label="weVVMpxFznicWC"></ApplicationRef>
  <AssociatedForm id="id80" role="IMAN_master_form" formRef="#id78"></AssociatedForm>
</Product>

<Form id="id48" name="1234" accessRefs="#id4" subType="Item Master" subClass="Item Master">  
  <UserData id="id49" type="FormAttributes">    
    <UserValue value="Class1" title="form_type"></UserValue>    
  </UserData>
</Form>
<Form id="id63" name="BXU004846" accessRefs="#id4" subType="Item Master" subClass="Item Master">  
  <UserData id="id64" type="FormAttributes">    
    <UserValue value="Class1" title="form_type"></UserValue>    
  </UserData>
</Form>
<Form id="id78" name="BXU004848" accessRefs="#id4" subType="Item Master" subClass="Item Master">  
  <UserData id="id79" type="FormAttributes">    
    <UserValue value="Class2" title="form_type"></UserValue>    
  </UserData>
</Form>
```

In the above xml,
- ProductRevision node is related to Product Node through 'masterRef' value. 'masterRef' id on ProductRevision
is equal to 'id' value on Product node.
- Product node is related to Form node through 'formRef' value. 'formRef' id on Product/AssociatedForm/formRef is
equal to 'id' value of Form node.
In the above example i have to find the latest date_released of ProductRevision with form_type 'Class1' (form_type
value is in Form node).

For example to find if first ProductRevision node is of type Class1:
- Go to Product node (id36) and get its formRef id (id48) - product/AssociatedForm/formRef
- Search Form xml nodes with id value as id48. In Form node, get form_type value and check if its 'Class1'.
- If its Class1, to get date_released we have to go to corresponding ProductRevision node.
- Search ProductRevision nodes with masterRef value as id36. Get date_released form ProductRevision node.

I was able to write logic to traverse the nodes and check form_type value and get date_released, but stuck on how to get latest date_released from these nodes.
Requirement is to get latest date_released of ProductRevision's with form_type as 'Class1'.

Comment: Your XSL code sample is missing.
Also, are you trying to get the most recent `UserValue/@value` attribute where the `title` attribute is "date_released"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. I don't know why but XSL code I placed is not getting displayed in the Question. Anyway, I only managed to get the date_released of ProductionRevision and got stuck on how to get date_released of each node, compare and get the lastet date.

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your XSLT? An `xsl:for-each` can only appear in a sequence constructor and an `xsl:key` is a declaration, so the code snippet above does not seem to be valid. Also, are you using XSLT 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0? A fully working example with XML, XSLT and expected output XML (showing where it goes wrong) would be best.

Comment: This seems to be a replay of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630130/traversing-plmxml-in-xsl), with all its [flaws](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630130/traversing-plmxml-in-xsl#comment51556966_31630130) intact.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have added the clarifications for your comment in prev question.

Answer (score -1):

Your recent update brings a lot of complexity to your question. I've refactored the approach in these steps:

1. Match the `UserValue` nodes with form_type=Class1
2. Match the correspondant `AssociatedForm` by `formRef`.
3. Match the correspondant `ProductRevision` by `masterRef`, sorting by descending `value` of the title=date_released.
4. Get the first element of the resulting list.

The XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" version="4.01" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
<html>
<body>
<!--Step 1-->
<xsl:apply-templates select="Form/UserData/UserValue[@title='form_type' and @value='Class1']"></xsl:apply-templates>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="UserValue">
<!--Step 2-->
    <xsl:variable name="refId">#<xsl:value-of select="../../@id"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//AssociatedForm[@formRef=$refId]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AssociatedForm">
<!--Step 3-->
    <xsl:variable name="refId">#<xsl:value-of select="../@id"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="datereleased"><xsl:apply-templates select="//ProductRevision[@masterRef=$refId]/UserData/UserValue[@title='date_released']" mode="max"><xsl:sort select="@value" data-type="text" order="descending"/></xsl:apply-templates></xsl:variable>
    <p>datereleased=<xsl:value-of select="$datereleased"/></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="UserValue" mode="max">
<!--Step 4-->
<xsl:if test="position()=1"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: `data-type on xsl:sort must be 'text' or 'number'`

Comment: Right. I've corrected it in my code. Due to the chosen date format, type=text works anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the approach. This is my 1st week into learning xslt so took some time for me to understand the logic.
Actually my requirement has got a little more complex. I have edited the question, can you please take a look at it.

Comment: I've posted a new approach. Most important is: Read the algorithm and try to understand it. XSL processing is based upon two actions: selecting desired nodes through XPATH expressions and processing each node through a template.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer. I have a doubt in the sorting logic. When we execute Step3, it will get date_released of only 1 ProductRevision node (as masterRef is different for each ProductRevision node. My Mistake I've given same masterRef value in the above XML example. Updated it now). Since there is only one value it is passing the condition in step4. Next time when we are processing the second Form node it will get date_released of second ProductRevision node and that will again pass step4 condition.

Comment: Yes. Was not that the intention? Please post the exact input XML and the expected result.